# HTML tag in text using embed.js

Tags: javascript, html, draw.io

I wanted to show a diagram on a web page using draw.io's embed.js script. There is one rectangle visible on the web page, but the text is: `<div>A</div><div>B<br></div>` (originally there were no tags, just A and B in separate lines).

The code:

```
<div id="mxfile" style="display: none;">
    %3cmxGraphModel%20dx%3d%222066%22%20dy%3d%221098%22%20grid%3d%221%22%20gridSize%3d%2210%22%20guides%3d%221%22%20tooltips%3d%221%22%20connect%3d%221%22%20arrows%3d%221%22%20fold%3d%221%22%20page%3d%221%22%20pageScale%3d%221%22%20pageWidth%3d%22827%22%20pageHeight%3d%221169%22%20background%3d%22%23ffffff%22%20math%3d%220%22%20shadow%3d%220%22%3e%0d%0a%20%20%3croot%3e%0d%0a%20%20%20%20%3cmxCell%20id%3d%220%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%20%20%20%20%3cmxCell%20id%3d%221%22%20parent%3d%220%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%20%20%20%20%3cmxCell%20id%3d%222%22%20value%3d%22%26lt%3bdiv%26gt%3bA%26lt%3b%2fdiv%26gt%3b%26lt%3bdiv%26gt%3bB%26lt%3bbr%26gt%3b%26lt%3b%2fdiv%26gt%3b%22%20style%3d%22rounded%3d0%3bwhiteSpace%3dwrap%3bhtml%3d1%3b%22%20vertex%3d%221%22%20parent%3d%221%22%3e%0d%0a%20%20%20%20%20%20%3cmxGeometry%20x%3d%2220%22%20y%3d%2220%22%20width%3d%22120%22%20height%3d%2260%22%20as%3d%22geometry%22%20%2f%3e%0d%0a%20%20%20%20%3c%2fmxCell%3e%0d%0a%20%20%3c%2froot%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fmxGraphModel%3e
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.draw.io/embed.js"></script>
```

To create the contents of the div I exported a diagram from draw.io's online editor (where text is shown correctly) to XML and URL-encoded it.

I've also used this script:

```
<script>
    var DRAW_IFRAME_URL = 'https://www.draw.io/?embed=1';
    var graph = null;
    var xml = null;

    function mxClientOnLoad(stylesheet) {
        xml = document.getElementById('mxfile').innerHTML;
        xml = decodeURIComponent(xml);

        // Removes all illegal control characters before parsing
        var checked = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
            var code = xml.charCodeAt(i);

            // Removes all control chars except TAB, LF and CR
            if (code >= 32 || code == 9 || code == 10 || code == 13) {
                checked.push(xml.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        xml = checked.join('');

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = '100%';
        div.style.height = '100%';
        div.style.position = 'relative';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        graph = new mxGraph(div);

        graph.resetViewOnRootChange = false;
        graph.foldingEnabled = false;
        // NOTE: Tooltips require CSS
        graph.setTooltips(false);
        graph.setEnabled(false);

        // Loads the stylesheet
        if (stylesheet != null) {
            var xmlDoc = mxUtils.parseXml(stylesheet);
            var dec = new mxCodec(xmlDoc);
            dec.decode(xmlDoc.documentElement, graph.getStylesheet());
        }

        var xmlDoc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
        var codec = new mxCodec(xmlDoc);
        codec.decode(codec.document.documentElement, graph.getModel());
        graph.maxFitScale = 1;
        graph.fit();
        graph.center(true, false);

        window.addEventListener('resize',
            function () {
                graph.fit();
                graph.center(true, false);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual results you see?

Comment: I expected "A" and "B" in separate lines, but see "<div>A</div><div>B<br></div>" as the actual caption.